# Smoothness for morphism of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \to Y$ be a projective morphism of schemes of finite type with $Y = Spec(R)$, where $R$ is a dvr. For this morphism to be smooth, is it sufficient to check smoothness on only closed points of $X$?

Comment: You mean checking only at closed points on the base (i.e. $X$)? If so, note that definitionally if $f$ is smooth at $x\in X$, it's smooth in a neighborhood of $x$. Thus, with mild conditions this is true (e.g. if $X$ is 'Jacobson'=all locally closed subsets contain a closed point). You might be able to get away with the conditions on $X$ if you also assume that $f$ is flat, so you can check smoothness on fibers.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, there exists an open subscheme $U$ of $X$ containing all closed points of $X$ such that $U \to Y$ is smooth. If $U \not= X$, then $X \backslash U$ is a closed subscheme and the morphism from $X$ to $Y$ is singular at each point on $X \backslash U$. But $X \backslash U$ is quasi-compact, hence contains closed points. This contradicts the first sentence. So $U$ must coincide with $X$.